# How to revert back to previous commit and make it the default branch Ignoring any further commits

Tags: git, github

I want to revert back to a previous commit and make it my new default branch in a clean way. Ignoring any future commits.

this what I did:

```
git checkout <commit-hash>
git branch new-main
```

How to make the new-main branch the default branch and make the development continue from there?

Comment: The "default branch" only exists in _git_ as far as creating new repos goes, if you want to change the default in _GitHub_ see https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch.

Comment: I want to "git push" that specific commit ignoring any forward commits. that's what I meant @jonrsharpe

Comment: And you can't just push it the normal way why?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was under the impression that OP meant his `main` branch when writing "default branch". @Ahmed?

Comment: I simply wanted to continue from a previous commit. the approved answer met my requirements. @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IF** (not 100% sure that's what you're asking but it sounds like it) you want your `main` branch to be set to the same commit `new-main` is currently at, the typical course of action would be **(from a clean working tree, or else your uncommitted changes will be lost)**

```
$ git checkout main
$ git reset --hard new-main
```

This is for your local repo.

Then **IF** your remote `main` is still pointing at the old (unwanted) commit, you won't be able to push without `--force`, so be sure to check with your team if this is okay in your context.

---

**Addition after comments** (making a backup "just in case"), before pushing the new position of `main` to the remote, create a backup with a tag

```
$ git tag <name> -m "This is the old position we rolled back because XYZ" origin/main
$ git push origin --tags
```

Comment: `git push --force` deletes all the earlier commits entirely. Is there a way to keep them in case reverting back?

Comment: Of course, keeping a way to rollback is indeed good practice. You can create a new branch or even better, a tag, pointing at your (remote) main, then do the push. You'd then be able to reset to that backup position if needed, and `push --force` again to return to the initial situation of your question here. IF your remote is named "origin", that could be something like `git tag <name-your-tag> -m "This is the old position we rolled back because XYZ" origin/main`